# HTML double-encoded in "No, my question is different."

Tags: bug, status-completed

I got this text:

```
No, my question is different. <a id="edit-instead" href="/posts/1620964/edit">I will edit to explain how.</a>
```

expected:

> No, my question is different. [I will edit to explain how.](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1620964/edit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be fixed by now, according to [this exchange on Twitter](https://twitter.com/CodingLady/status/690249161980030976):

[image: bird]

Comment: So now we have TwitterExchange too?